# Unable to access ExpressJS endpoints NuxtJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment, nuxt.js

I am fairly new to Nuxt and Vue. I have worked with React and Express before but I'm not sure if I'm missing a step specific to the Nuxt configuration.

I'm trying to GET data from an endpoint on my Express server, and it's working fine locally, but once I've deployed it, I'm having one of a couple of different errors. At first I was getting

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/ENDPOINT' from
>   origin 'https://APPNAME.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

I was able to get past this by installing the cors and @nuxtjs/proxy npm packages, adding app.use(cors()) to my server and adding a `changeOrigin` property to `proxy` in nuxt.config.js.. Now I'm getting a 404  when it tries to GET APPNAME.herokuapp.com/ENDPOINT.

I created a new test app using npx create-nuxt-app, choosing express as the custom server framework and setting up a test endpoint in server/index.js

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('reached test')
})
```

In my nuxt view, I added a method:

```
runTest () {
  this.$axios.$get('/test')
    .then(success => console.log('success text:', success))
}
```

Again, this runs fine locally, but once deployed, I got the CORS issue until I added the cors package and changeOrder. Now getting the 404, it seems like I can't access my server's endpoints. Does anyone know anything about this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

## UPDATE:

My `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.npm_package_name,
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/': ''
      },
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
  },
  /*
  ** vuetify module configuration
  ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
  */
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {}
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

My server file:

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const cors = require('cors')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

async function start () {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  await nuxt.ready()
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  app.use(cors())

  app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('reached test')
  })

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

This is mostly default nuxt scaffolding on my test app.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show me your `nuxt.config.js` and your server js file?

Comment: Hey @ifaruki, thanks for your response! I've added the files you asked about

Comment: Still trying to figure this out.. In my search for answers I've seen mention of using a `server/api` folder for routes... Am I supposed to be doing this? Could this be causing my issues? It just doesn't make sense since it works fine locally.